# Amazon RDS change collate for database in production

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Currently my database is using **en_US.UTF-8** COLLATE but, due to ordering preferences, I want to use **'pt-PT-x-icu'** collation (Amazon RDS already supports icu provider [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/collation.html)).
In the Amazon RDS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html) they say it is possible to change COLLATE of a db by

> ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE pt-PT-x-icu;

but a error is thrown saying

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CHARACTER"

Is there another way to change collate? Keep in mind this is already in prod, I don't want to delete the database.

I also tried updating pg_database, but not even root user has permissions to do that in the Amazon RDS system.

Can we do it through Amazon RDS dashboard?

Comment: Is your database name also a SQL keyword? Try wrapping it \`\`

Comment: I just noticed you mentioned postgres. I think this is only possible with mysql. SO answers on the topic indicate it can't be changed in postgres.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Amazon docs.  The previous paragraph says it can't be changed after creation, then it gives an *obviously broken* method to change it after creation.

Comment: Instead of database level, is it possible at column/table level?